# Multiple % in Make target pattern

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching

Is it possible to match a pattern in GNU `make` with multiple `%` expressions? Say, I have a couple of targets which consist of two words, separated by an underscore, and I need to access both in the prerequisites, e.g. the target `hello_world` should require `hello` and `world`. One of the two is from a limited set, the other should match anything. I came up with

```
GREETING=hello hi howdy
$(addsuffix _%,$(GREETING)): % ???
```

Thus, I can extract the single `%` but I found no way to access the greeting that was used. I do have the full match, `@`. (Sure, you could sort of hack it, replacing the underscore by a space and using `findstring`, but I'm looking for something more generic.)

Ideally, there would be a way to resolve multiple `%`-like unknowns, like you can have multiple capture groups in regular expressions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but GNU `make` cannot be used this way as far as I know.

Comment: As @FUZxxl indicates GNU make can't do what you want here. There are various ways to get things sort-of like what you want depending on what your targets look like and where the lists come from but they aren't "generic" in the real sense.

Comment: Interesting. Is it an unreasonable feature to ask for? In my particular use case, I have several `gnuplot` scripts and I would like to use `make` to distill them into plots for different sets of data. E.g. `make test_4.eps` is supposed to call `gnuplot -e "j=4" test.gp`. I can do that with one rule per gnuplot file. I would like to have one rule for multiple files, not just `test.gp`. Is there a better way to do things?

Comment: @Jonas did you ever resolve this? I'm currently trying the same thing!

Comment: I'm afraid I ended up working around the issue.